# Running python script on Android local server

Tags: android, python, machine-learning, chatbot, chatterbot

I need to build a chatbot which does not takes any online support.
I am using:

- Python chatterbot to build conversation dialogues.
- Android's google offline speech recognition to convert speech to text and vice versa.

I want to train the model on my PC and use the generated database.sqlite3 file on android.

The complete flow of the process is as follows:

1. Pretrained model generated database.sqlite3 which is placed in android.
2. **Voice -> Text -> Local Android Server which runs python script using database.sqlite3 and generates response(text) -> Text to Voice**

Now I have the problem of running Python on Android with all the environment needed to run the script on android. Kindly help me out with this.

I have searched stuffs and found setting local server on android using NanoHTTPD/AndroidSync. Now I want to use this server to run python script

**If you have any better alternative to any of the steps above, kindly suggest.**

Comment: After so many trial and error, I was able to run chatterbot completely in Android by using [Chaquopy](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/11.0/index.html) .

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, trying to get Python running on Android doesn't sound like the best way to accomplish this. I'd recommend splitting your project up into two parts:

**1. A web application hosted somewhere**

You can create a regular web application using a Python framework like Django or Flask. This application can provide a [RESTful API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) that allows other applications to exchange information with your chat bot.

ChatterBot has built-in support for Django and there are numerous examples of the two being used together available. You can also take a look at the "[How do I deploy my chat bot to the web?](http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html)" section for a brief overview and some tips on how to get started.

**2. The Android app**

The app can access Android's native speech recognition technologies to interpret verbal information before it sends the recognized text to your chat bot API server.

Comment: What about the "does not takes any online support" part?